# Oracle - How do I assign a default value to a variable when value is not found?

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, default

so I have a procedure in Oracle PL/SQL that makes use of a variable...
anyway, this variable gets its value from a function that gets the value somewhere else..

example:

```
lv_cell_value   varchar2(6) := f_get_system_parameter(lv_system_name, lv_param_section, 'BUSINESS_SUBTYPE_CELLULAR');
```

now say for example the variable lv_cell_value doesn't return anything, how would I go about assigning NULL to that variable?

Comment: A function can't return nothing at all; it would error if it tried to end without returning something. But it can return `null`, and if it did then your local variable would already be set to `null`. So is that already happening, or is your function not handling the unrecognised argument value and is maybe throwing a no-data-found exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this is what you are looking for but,

```
Coalesce(parameter1, parameter2)
```

might just do the job. Coalesce checks if the parameter1 is null, if yes, it returns parameter2. You can hardcode parameter2 to something or enter another query there.